# How to filter GCP Data Catalog entries with a specific tag value via console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp, google-data-catalog

I ran a DLP job saving results to Data Catalog and would like to filter the entries in Data Catalog where the standard tag template (`Data Loss Prevention Tags`) has a value `Contains DLP findings: true`. I know how to do it with the API. But is there a way to filter out by tag values via Console UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to filter out by tag values via the Data Catalogs Console using the search box. The below syntax can be used to achieve the results:

```
tag:<project_name>.tag_template_name.key:value
```

As per your requirement, the below query would work:

```
tag:<project_name>.data_loss_prevention.has_findings=true
```

The above query can be broken down as follows:

1. `<project_name>` (It is optional)
2. `data_loss_prevention` (tag_template_name of "**Data Loss Prevention Tags**")
3. `has_findings` (ID of "**Contains DLP findings**"). For every Display name, there should be an ID. The ID of the "Display name" from the “**View tag template**” should be used instead of the Display name as the key during search.
   [image]
4. `=` - Choose the `<operator>` based on the data type.

   - string: ":"  **Note**: The colon in this string search denotes an exact token match, not a substring.
   - boolean and enum: "="
   - double: "=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="
   - timestamp: ":", "=", "<", ">", "<=", ">="
5. `true` (The value of “Contains DLP findings”)

Answer (score 0):

```
tag:data_loss_prevention.has_finding
```

That'll work.